# Sorted values and values higher then 1 pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do i print only values from an pandas groupby that have more then 2 values

```
value1,value2,value3
hi,1,2
he,1,2
ho,1,2
hi,1,2
ho,1,2
hi,1,2
```

If an csv file has the values above and the csv file name is abo.csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('abo.csv')
test = df.groupby('value1').value2.count()
print(.....)
```

How can i make the print funktion print:

```
hi 3
ho 2
```

and skip he because it is only 1 time in the csv. I also want to print the highest value first (most common).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is an over-kill in this specific use case. Try [`pandas.Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) like this.

```
>>> values_counts = df.value1.value_counts()
>>> print(values_counts[values_counts >= 2])
hi    3
ho    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find how many times each one appears and then slice by just those:

```
df['num_occurences'] = df.groupby('value1')['value2'].transform(lambda x: len(x))

df[df['num_occurences']>1].groupby('value1').size()

value1
hi    3
ho    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks... Jaroslav Bezděk answer was smarter but your answer was gr8 to